# How do I prevent Intellij from removing line breaks for getters and setters

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm new to Intellij and this IDE is automatically removing new lines for my getters and setters putting them in one line !

```
public void setSocialNetwork(SocialNetwork socialNetwork) { this.socialNetwork = socialNetwork; }
```

I searched and found that I can use the following setting under Settings >> Code Style >> Java. However I have the wanted option selected but it still removes the new lines.

[image]

Comment: Do you mean _code folding_? You can disable it under `Editor -> General -> Code Folding -> Java -> One-line methods`.

Comment: Note that it's only _folding_ the methods _for display purposes_ and doesn't modify the actual file contents.

Comment: “Code folding” means visual representation- the code is as written behind that. It is a help.

Comment: That's weired. Thanks for the tip .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to the `Settings -> Editor -> General -> Code Folding` and uncheck the checkbox `One-line methods`

[image: One-line method]